# War takes more space

Tags: java, gwt

I am using GWT-JAVA. In this, WAR folder takes more memory. When i reduce my source file also it doesn't get reduced. 
What are all files/folder must be needed in WAR? Please give suggestion about needs of each file and folder?
Some of folders are images, smartG, Web-INF, sc, LS, js, pieces(In this, Sc and Web-INF takes more space).

I attached the image about the sc and Lib in the following URL.
http://rapidshare.com/files/415235782/War_folder.bmp

In my test system I am already having War folder. In Each and every time of testing What are all folders/files to be replaced?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *"In this, WAR folder takes more memory."* - WAR files and their contents are stored on disk, not in memory.  Please edit your question so that it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

To know what can be removed from your application (WAR) we first need to know what is in there exactly, what is used by your app and what is not. Check your WEB-INF/lib. Make sure you have only jars that are needed for your app.

How do you build your WAR? Ho do you manage dependencies? If you post a content of Sc folder, maybe we could help you more.

Comment: I posted my War details in the following URL
http://rapidshare.com/files/415235782/War_folder.bmp